# Does order in a declaration of multidimensional array have an influence on used memory?

Tags: java, arrays, memory

How many bytes will be allocated for `a` and `b`?

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

Bitmap[][][] a = new Bitmap[1000][2][2];
Bitmap[][][] b = new Bitmap[2][2][1000];
```

Note that I'm only asking about the memory taken by pure arrays, no objects inside.

<sub>Why I'm asking? Because I'm writing an Android game. For me the order doesn't matter, but if there is a memory difference, it will be good to save some.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it does make a difference.

In Java, a 2D array is an array of 1D arrays, and arrays (like all objects) have headers in addition to the space needed to hold the elements themselves.

So consider `int[10][2]` versus `int[2][10]`, and assume a 32 bit JVM.

- `int[2][10]` consists of one array of 2 elements, and 2 arrays of 10 elements. Total - 3 array objects + 22 elements.
- `int[10][2]` consists of one array of 10 elements, and 10 arrays of 2 elements.  Total - 11 array objects + 30 elements.

If we assume that the header size is 3 32-bit words (typical for a 32bit JVM) and a reference is 1 32-bit word, then

- `int[2][10]` takes 3*3 + 22*1 = 31 words = 124 bytes
- `int[10][2]` takes 11*3 + 30*1 = 63 words = 252 bytes

Apply the same logic and you can estimate the size of arrays with higher numbers of dimensions.

But it is clear that you use less space if the largest dimension is the right-most one.

---

<sub>I've done the math with `int` arrays, but on a 32 bit machine an `int` and a `reference` occupy the same number of bytes.  On a 64 bit machine, a reference can be the same size as an `int` or a `long`,  depending on JVM options.  The header sizes may also be different .... not exactly sure ... potentially platform dependent.</sub>

<sub>I've not accounted for the space required to hold the `Bitmap` objects themselves, but it is the same however you organize the arrays.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! I have one question. Maybe the best way to save memory will be `Bitmap[] c = new Bitmap[2*1000]` and later calculating index like `1000*i + j`? There will be no speed difference compared to `Bitmap[2][1000]`?

Comment: 1) Yes ... though it makes your code harder to read and the incremental saving is not great. 2) A 1D array *might* be faster because there are fewer array bounds checks and fewer fetches.  However, the difference is most likely too small to make any differences.

Comment: Note that on 64 bit hotspot for example, references are compressed to 4 bytes by default.

Comment: @assylias - True, but that doesn't affect the overall picture.

Comment: @StephenC it does not - only a side comment.

Answer (score 3):

When trying it on hotspot (the exact figures might be different from those you get on dalvik, but the conclusions should be similar), I get the following results:

> Object array (1000x2x2): 76034 bytes
>   Object array (2x2x1000): 16137 bytes

This is in line with a rough calculation:

```
[2][2][1000]                    
Array #     Header  Size  Memory  Number    Total
1             16       2      24       1       24
2             16       2      24       2       48
3             16    1000    4016       4   16,064

                         Grand Total       16,136


[1000][2][2]                    
Array #     Header  Size  Memory  Number    Total
1             16    1000    4016       1    4,016
2             16       2      24    1000   24,000
3             16       2      24    2000   48,000

                         Grand Total       76,016
```

---

Test code below, run with `-XX:-UseTLAB` to get more accurate results.

```
public class TestMemory {

    private static final int SIZE = 100;
    private static Runnable r;
    private static Object o;

    private static void test(Runnable r, String name, int numberOfObjects) {
        long mem = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        r.run();
        System.out.println(name + ": " + (mem - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / numberOfObjects + " bytes");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new Object[1000][2][2];} };
        test(r, "Object array (1000x2x2)", SIZE);

        r = new Runnable() { public void run() { for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) o = new Object[2][2][1000];} };
        test(r, "Object array (2x2x1000)", SIZE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that surprising that this is not optimized? The difference is huge and many people are unaware of this. Such sorting numbers written between [] in ascending order should be doable, isn't it?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk I knew it was different but had never calculated the difference. It is indeed huge. And I see no reason why it could not be optimised since you can't "move pointers" so I don't see what negative impacts it would have...

Answer (score 3):

Yes it makes a difference. Just try this with `-Xmx8M`:

```
// throws OutOfMemoryError
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = new int[500000][2];
    System.out.println("a.length: '" + (a.length) + "'");
}

// works
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = new int[2][500000];
    System.out.println("a.length: '" + (a.length) + "'");
}
```

The first one will throw an OutOfMemoryError, the second one will pass.

The reason is, that the first version creates 500.000 arrays of length 2, while the second one creates 2 Arrays of length 500.000.

[Reference](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/array_memory_usage.shtml):

> In a language such as C, a two-dimensional array (or indeed any multidimensional array) is essentially a one-dimensional array with judicious pointer manipulation. This is not the case in Java, where a multidimensional array is actually a set of nested arrays. This means that every row of a two-dimensional array has the overhead of an object, since it actually is a separate object!

Answer (score -1):

No memory difference, but the order of your array indices could
- in theory - have an influence on your program's speed.

You usually process multi-dimensional array contents in nested loops. So your array should be organized in a way that you address adjacent elements in your inner loop to allow the compiler to produce the most efficient code. I do not know how Java organizes memory but think it is not different to C/C++:

```
int a[10][100];
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
        do_something_with(a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You usually process multi-dimensional array contents in nested loops. So your array should be organized in a way that you address adjacent elements in your inner loop to allow the conpiler to produce the most efficient code. I do not know how java organizes memory but think it is not different to C/C++:  


    int a[10[100];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      for (j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
        do_soemething_with (a[i][j]);