# Java: Adding new items in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

For school I have to make a program which will get values from a file and then print them off. I am using a `HashMap` because it makes the most sense for storing my data. The Problem I have is that when I try to add to it I get a null pointer. Maybe this is because the integer is not instantiated, but how would I do that?
Here is my code:

```
public class Driver {

static ArrayList<Event> myEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();
static String[][][] counts = new String[50][1000][2];


//static ArrayList<int>[] myCounts = new ArrayList[];
//static ArrayList<String>[] myCountProfile = new ArrayList[];

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static HashMap<String, Integer>[] count = new HashMap[50];

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File input = new File("./src/Problem1/stormdata_2013.csv");
    Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(input);


    while (fileRead.hasNextLine()) {
        String currentLine = fileRead.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(currentLine).useDelimiter(",");

        // Dealing with unnecessary information
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            lineScan.next();
        }
        String state = lineScan.next().trim();
        int stateNum = Integer.parseInt(lineScan.next());
        lineScan.next();
        String month = lineScan.next().trim();
        String type = lineScan.next().trim();

        myEvents.add(new Event(type, month, state, stateNum));

        count[stateNum].put(type,count[stateNum].get(type)+1);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Oh my. I don't know where to start. I suggest you use a debugger and narrow down your issue to a more specific one then edit your question

Comment: Your program as you typed in the question doesn't even compile.

Comment: When asking about an error, always post the entire error message, including the stack trace for any exception, and point out which line it's talking about.

Comment: To avoid an error from the input, use a try/catch around the line where you parse the input string to an int.

Comment: How could someone even close this as "too broad"?

Answer (score 2):

You've created an array of `HashMap`s:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static HashMap<String, Integer>[] count = new HashMap[50];
```

... but the maps in that array are not initialized. Your array just contains 50 `null` references. You've to initialize them first with a `map`, before putting anything to it.

```
if (count[stateNum] == null) {
    countNum[stateNum] = new HashMap<String, Integer();
}
count[stateNum].put(type,count[stateNum].get(type)+1);
```

Also, I would suggest you to create a `List<Map<String, Integer>>`, instead of creating array of raw type. That is really not type-safe, as pointed out by the compiler.

Also, the fact that you've to use `String[][][]`, clearly show that you've perhaps not chosen the best data structure, that could have helped you. I would guess, you almost certainly need a separate class here.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating even single HashMap. You create an array for 50 HashMaps. By default it contains 50 nulls, it must contain 50 new HashMap objects.

Also, write `String[2][50][1000]` instead of `String[50][1000][2]` to not waste the memory. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339296/memory-usage-of-multidimensional-array-does-the-order-makes-difference).

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your Array of `HashMap`'s, but not initialized it.

```
static HashMap<String, Integer>[] count = new HashMap[50];
```

Before using it, you need to initialize all of the elements of the HashMap

Answer (score 0):

To use HashMap, you could do the following and should never get nullpointer exception:

```
static HashMap<String, Object[]>    hm  = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File input = new File("./src/Problem1/stormdata_2013.csv");
        Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(input);

        while (fileRead.hasNextLine()) {
            String currentLine = fileRead.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(currentLine).useDelimiter(",");

            // Dealing with unnecessary information
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                lineScan.next();
            }
            String state = lineScan.next().trim();
            int stateNum = Integer.parseInt(lineScan.next());
            lineScan.next();
            String month = lineScan.next().trim();
            String type = lineScan.next().trim();

            Object[] obj = { stateNum, state, month };
            hm.put(type, obj);

    }
```