# java lang OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I have declared a three dimensional array as

```
double mat[][][] = new mat[400][400][3];
```

but i am getting memory error, maybe i need to increase my heap memory. How can i do it?

```
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.sulabh.phaseonimage, PID: 3610
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2572 byte allocation with  952 free bytes and 952B until OOM
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Array.createMultiArray(Native Method)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:335)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.sulabh.phaseonimage.MainActivity.reshape2Dcolre(MainActivity.java:743)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.sulabh.phaseonimage.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:441)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3573)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3620)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-21 15:21:43.587 3610-3610/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: It's likely this is just a symptom of a larger memory leak.  Your app under normal execution should not have a problem allocating `2572` bytes.

Comment: Can you see any "grow heap" line at the logcat?

Comment: first of all get rid of multidimensional array ... [why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339296/does-order-in-a-declaration-of-multidimensional-array-have-an-influence-on-used) , [naive benchmark](http://ideone.com/cneoAK)

Answer (score 0):

You might use largeHeap - please read http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/articles/memory.html and http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap - but think twice before doing this - there might be other options and this should be the last resort